# What projects cannot be done in C?

Tags: c

I would like to know what projects cannot be done in C.

I know programming can be quicker and more intuitive in
other languages. But I would like to know what features
are missing in C that would prevent a project from being
completed well.

For example, very few web-frameworks exist in C.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting voted down, it seems like a valid question to me.  Maybe the OP was wondering why there are almost no web programming frameworks that use C, and thought maybe it's because it's impossible.

Comment: @Outlaw: It is likely downvoted because the question is born out of simple confusion about programming in general.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not so sure about closing this one, guys.  I think it's worth it to keep the answer around for future generations of noobs.

Comment: I cannot come up with a reason to close, but it is not a 'good' question for sure, so I can understand the downvotes.

Comment: I'm with Bill. It is programming related and *not* controversial or argumentative. Simply naive. Very, *very* naive. ::sigh::

Comment: If we make it our mission to remove all the naive questions, we will never be done.  They'll keep getting asked because we removed them.

Comment: @Bill: Who are you even arguing with?

Comment: C was often used for web programming in the early days, both for ASAPI extensions and for CGI programs

Comment: @Rich: I guess no one at this point?

Comment: Ack! spoke too soon.  I'm arguing with whoever closed the question!

Comment: @Bill: Why bother? Just open it back up. The reason is clearly invalid.

Comment: I will admit that I was very borderline on my close vote for this one. So if it gets 4 opens I would provide the 5th. After some further thought and considering the comments I think I would reopen it.

Comment: @EBGreen: I have no idea what logic people used to close it under our valid close reasons...

Comment: Well, I was one of the people. I voted because the question just didn't make sense to me. To me it was like asking "What stories can't be told in english?" Reading the comments changed my opinion.

Comment: And by not making sense it became Not A Real Question.

Comment: All this talk about how "naive" and "invalid" the question is, yet not a single answer from any of you!  Have you considered spending more time answering questions, and less time tearing down people who want to learn?

Comment: I swear I've seen this question before. I think it's a dupe.

Comment: @Bill: How many answers of  what turing complete means do we need?

Comment: @Gortok: it sounds a lot like the not-infrequent "What can Ruby do that SNOBOL can't?" questions we see around here.

Comment: @Bill - There is an answer already present that I feel is correct. I voted it up. That is the SO way to do things.

Comment: That's fine to mark a question as a duplicate and direct the OP to the entry that can help them.  Dissing them as naive and invalid, however, is not helpful, and in fact is pretty boorish.

Comment: I didn't know that it was a duplicate. Could you point to the post that it is a duplicate of?

Comment: I think this is kind of on the chopping block. All the answers are basically useless jibber jabber. I don't know what value this adds. Not voting to close though, just stating my thoughts.

Comment: If it can't be written in assembly language; it's not worth writing!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

C, like many other languages, is [Turing Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete).

So simple answer is: none.

However, C++ Template Meta Programming meets the same criterion, so "it is possible" is not a good criterion to choose tools.

Comment: I added the link to Wikipedia's 'Turing Completeness' article for completeness.

Comment: For any problem that cannot be (easily) solved in C but can be easily solved in another language, you can always write an interpreter for that other language in C and then use that language's program as data.

Answer (score 19):

The very first C compiler?

Comment: wasn't that written in C as well? A Bootstraping compiler?

Comment: I don't know about C specifically, but compilers are often written in their own language (even the first one).

Comment: @EBGreen: What do you compile the first C compiler written in C with?  Not being snarky, I'm sincerely interested to know how that works.

Comment: The first compile of the compiler is by hand based on the language grammar.

Comment: The *very first* compiler for a language cannot be written in the language itself, since there is no compiler there to compile it ;)
Often those have been written by hand or in a different language but after the first run you can use the generated compiler itself.

Comment: looks like there's a few ways it could be done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: If I recall my C history, the C compiler evolved incrementally from a B compiler.

Comment: The first C compiler was written in hand-crafted assembler. Only later did it get rewritten in C. Later came Stephen C. Johnson's PCC (Portable C Compiler) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_C_Compiler

Comment: @Bill - As I said I don't know about C specifically, but you could certainly hand compile the first compiler.

Answer (score 10):

A working solution to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 4):

Alright, here's one: you cannot write an x86 boot sector in C. This is one of those things that **has to be written** in ASM.

Comment: And boot sector can also be written in C, if you have more than 512KiB of space to use and some smarter arch than x86 is.

Comment: Cheery: I've meant x86 of course. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure I'd say that, although to do it in C, you would need a C run-time library and linker specific to the task.

Comment: James: It's not just the library - you need a boot signature, you need to know that it's loaded to 0x7c00, you have 512 bytes max etc. That would be a very very special linker.

Comment: Wait, you can't?  Can't you just queue up the 512 bytes of space, and point the bios to that after setting up the registers for the int21h call to write a hard drive sector?  All this can be done in C, and has been available since, well, forever.  Check out free Turbo C 2.xx...

Comment: I have it on good grounds that a certain hamburgler and pesto concoction has created an x86 boot sector in gcc.

Comment: Now, are we talking about a hard-disk bootstrap or a BIOS?  For a HD, those are mostly (common) features of the sector writing utility.  For BIOS, setting the load address is a standard feature of any linker (check link /? for the /BASE: option)

Comment: No, we are talking about the code in the boot sector that is called by the BIOS and is responsible for loading the proper boot loader or the kernel from the disk and possibly setting up protected mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are none.

Different languages give you different ways to say things. For some classes of problems a given language may be more expressive and/or concise. Are there projects that you should pick something aside from C? Yes, of course. But to say you can't do it well in C is misleading. It would be better to ask which language is the best choice for the problem at hand, and are the gains worth using something unfamiliar?

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be done in virtually any language.

That said there is a level of practicality.  As your system's complexity increases, you need better tools to manage it.

The problems are still solvable, but you start to need more people and much more effort in design.  I'm not saying other languages don't benefit from design, I'm saying that the same level and attention to detail may not be required.

Since we programmers are Human (I am at least) we have troubles in one area or another.  My biggest is memory.  If I can visualize my code as objects, manipulating large modules in my head becomes easier, and my brain can handle larger projects.

Of course, it's even possible to write good OO code in C, the patterns were developed in C by manually managing dispatch tables (tables of pointers with some pointers updated to point to different methods), and this is true of all programming constructs from higher languages--they can be done in any language, but...

If you were to implement objects in C, every single class you wrote would have a large amount of boilerplate overhead.  If you made some form of exception handling, you would expose more boilerplate.

Higher level languages abstract this boilerplate out of your code and into the system, simplifying what you have to think about and debug (a dispatch table in C could take a lot of debugging, but in C++ it isn't going to fail because the code generated by a working compiler is going to be bug-free and hidden, you never see it).

I guess I'd say that's the biggest (only?) difference between low level and higher level languages, how much boilerplate do you hide.  In the latest batch of dynamic languages, they are really into hiding loop constructs within the language, so more things look like:

directory.forEachFile(print file.name);  // Not any real language

In C, even if you isolated part of the looping inside a function, setting up the function pointers and stuff would still take lines of un-obvious code that is not solving part of your primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single algorithm that cannot be written with C.

Comment: That depends on your definition of algorithm.

Comment: even non-computable functions?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you want to invest (time/money/energy) to make it happen.  Otherwise, I'd say there aren't any.  It is just easier sometimes to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

OS kernel has been written in C and everything runs over it so you can write *everything* in C.

Boot sector that needs ASM :-) , I don't think you meant that.

Comment: your logic is very, very flawed.

Comment: Boot sectors do not /require/ ASM.

Comment: Most operating systems have parts that require assembler, too.  Of course, you can "write" assembler in C with asm() statements...